# A Pythagorean quadruple-like equation: $(2a^2)^2+(ab)^2+2^2=c^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am looking for a general solution to

> $$(2a^2)^2+(ab)^2+4=c^2$$
>   where $a,b,c, \in\mathbb{Z^+}$

In fact, it is possible to find the values ​​that work. But, I am looking for a general solution. At least, I want to know if there are infinitely many solutions to this equation.

My effort is only research and brute-force. I found that this equation looks like [Pythagorean quadruple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple).But, I have no idea what kind of method can be applied to the equation above. And I don't know if this equation can be solved by elementary number theory.I don't know anything about the Method. So, it's pointless to talk about my steps.

Comment: It might help to tell us where you found this equation.  What makes you think that a general solution exists?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking $(a,b)=(n,n^3)$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have
$$(2n^2)^2+(n\cdot n^3)^2+4=4n^4+n^8+4=(n^4+2)^2$$
So we have infinitely many solutions given by
$$(a,b,c)=(n,n^3,n^4+2)\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Comment: (+1) Impressive work. This answer provides the first part of my question. Am I right?

Comment: I mean Your work provide an answer a question of  "Are there infinitely many solutions?"  .    We say Yes. But , Are these solutions contain all possible solution?

Comment: Clearly not for example $$(a,b,c)=(3, 13, 43)$$I don't believe every possible solution is part of a single generalisation.

Comment: I understood Thank you very much for your  answer.